# line 6, in <module> get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline') AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_line_magic'

Tags: python

Im new in Python . I am getting error on the following python code.

Running this code on python .Now use version 3.6.5.. Btw, I have installed the pip install ipython.

my code is :

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

import somoclu

from IPython import get_ipython

get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
```

the result :

```
line 6, in <module>
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_line_magic'
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40721660/error-executing-python-script-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute for your answer.

Comment: You don't get an `ImportError`?  What do you get if you just `print(get_ipython)` after the import statement?

Comment: why it says no attribute for run_line_magic ?

Comment: because for some reason `get_ipython()` returns `None` and `None` objects do not have a method `run_line_magic`

Answer (score 0):

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('inline')
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).